# Constraints are working on iOS 8, but not on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm trying to show a `UITableView` when a user presses the navigation bar button. My table view is built on the interface builder and I give it these constraints:

1. Trailing space to: superView.
2. Top space to: top layout guide.
3. Width.
4. Height.

(The table view should be at the top right side of the viewController's view when the user press at the button).

Now, I don't know why, but it works perfectly on iOS 8, but on iOS 7 the table is losing some pixels from the right (it slides outside from the view). I've noticed it can happen on labels too. Can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: Can you upload some photos of this in action? It is a little hard to imagine what is actually going on. Also what device are you running on?

Comment: do you have any warnings in your project 
like 
"Attribute Unavailable Layout attributes relative to the layout margin on iOS versions prior to 8.0."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode 6, the Layout Constraints are set against the Margin of the superview. That only works in ios 8 though. To get the old behavior, you need to select a constraint from IB, go to Attributes Inspector and see if the first or second item is set to margins.

For example:`First Item: Superview.trailing Margin`

Click on it and **uncheck** "Relative to margin". You will have to do that to all your constraints.